# Fulltext stoplist replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

In MS SQL Server 2008 R2 there is replication of table with fulltext index on it.
But stoplist that is associated with replicated fulltext index doesn't replicate.

Is there any possibility to replicate stoplist also?

Comment: Apologies for the short response but... No.

Answer (score 1):

stoplist can't be replicated but there is one ugly way to do it. Words in Stop lists are stored in sys.fulltext_stopwords . Using linked server you can query this table and compare it on secondary server . If there are any changes then run alter command on secondary to add\remove those changes from stoplist.

ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST YourStopLIstName ADD 'en' LANGUAGE 'Spanish';

Can be setup as recurring job. Not a decent method but should work fine.

Comment: Note that a change in the Stoplist does not reindex existing content. If that is required you would also need to start a full population. E.g. ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable START FULL POPULATION;